# Configuration Binding extension could not be found, Binding exists but service can't see it

Tags: c#, wcf

I've tried using all the solutions that I could find but have been unable to get it working.  I'm trying to connect my local machine to a server where the connection is https.  The latest error that I'm getting is :-

Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/WSHttpBinding_IService' could not be found. Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is spelled correctly.

When I look at my web.config, I can see WSHttpBinding_IService in the bindings section.  I wonder what I'm doing wrong.  My web.config is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="baseaddress" value="https://Silvertest.Example.com/Silver"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="" connectionString=""/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>

<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework ="4.5"  />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="Silver" >
    <endpoint address=""  binding="WSHttpBinding_IService" contract="IService"  />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://Silvertest.Example.com/Silver/service.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service >
</services>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://Silvertest.Example.com/Silver/Service.svc"
    binding="WSHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
    contract="IService" name="SecureWCF" />
</client>
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="https" binding="WSHttpBinding_IService" bindingConfiguration="SecureWCF" />
</protocolMapping>
<extensions>
  <endpointExtensions>

  </endpointExtensions>
</extensions>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
      textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType ="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>

  </wsHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding closeTimeout="10:01:00" openTimeout="10:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
      sendTimeout="10:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
      messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRemote" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled  ="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="SecureWCF">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled  ="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client and server endpoint config is wrong for starters. Try this:

```
<endpoint address="https://Silvertest.Example.com/Silver/Service.svc"
binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService"
contract="IService" name="SecureWCF" />
```

You must specify the `binding` and `bindingConfiguration` attributes for both the server and client endpoint elements. Make sure the binding configuration elements match too (unless you are using SSL offloading but I'm assuming you're not).

Comment: I made the change as you suggested, however, I still get the same error.  Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/WSHttpBinding_IService' could not be found. Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: Currently, am just trying to get it to work in the browser then worry about the client after.

Comment: If the casing on the binding is now correct, then it may be an ordering issue in the config. Check the order used by the serviceModel element as show in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731354%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I reorganised it but that didn't seem to have any effect nor did changing the case.

Comment: That second error message you get still says that you have the wrong value in `binding` attribute tho' - it must be `wsHttpBinding` to say that the type of binding is `wsHttpBinding`. `bindingConfiguration` is used to name which `wsHttpBinding` child it should be using.

Comment: I took out protocol settings and it seems to work now.  Now am getting a new error :-  Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service https://silvertest.example.com/Silver/Service.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.